# snakemake both shell I/O redirection and accessing snakemake variable using script

Tags: python, snakemake

The problem is very simple: 
I want to call a script from a rule and I would like that rule to both:

- Perform stdout and stderr redirection
- Access the snakemake variables from the script(variable can be both lists and literals)

If I use the `shell:` then, I can perform the I/O redirection but I cannot use the `snakemake` variable inside the script. 
Note: Of course it is possible to pass the variables to the script as arguments from the shell. However by doing so, the script cannot distinguish a literal and a list variable.

If I instead use `script:` then, I can access my snakemake variables but I cannot perform I/O redirection and many other shell facilities.

---

An example to illustrate the question: 
1) Using the `shell:`

```
rule create_hdf5:
    input:
        genes_file = OUTPUT_PATH+'/{sample}/outs/genes.tsv'
    params:
        # frequencies is a list!!!
        frequencies = config['X_var']['freqs']
    output:
        HDF5_OUTPUT+'/{sample}.h5'
    log:
        out = LOG_FILES+'/create_hdf5/sample_{sample}.out',
        err = LOG_FILES+'/create_hdf5/sample_{sample}.err'
    shell:
        'python scripts/create_hdf5.py {input.genes_file} {params.frequencies} {output} {threads} 2> {log.err} 1> {log.out} '
```

Problem with 1): Naturally, the python script thinks that each element in the frequencies list is a new argument. Yet, the script cannot access the `snakemake` variable.

2) Using the `script:`

```
rule create_hdf5:
    input:
        genes_file = OUTPUT_PATH+'/{sample}/outs/genes.tsv'
    params:
        # frequencies is a list!!!
        frequencies = config['X_var']['freqs']
    output:
        HDF5_OUTPUT+'/{sample}.h5'
    log:
        out = LOG_FILES+'/create_hdf5/sample_{sample}.out',
        err = LOG_FILES+'/create_hdf5/sample_{sample}.err'
    script:
        'scripts/create_hdf5.py'
```

Problem with 2): I can access the snakemake variable inside the script. But now I cannot use the bash facilities such as I/O redirection.

I wonder if there is a way of achieving both (perhaps I am missing something from the snakemake documentation)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can seriealize the list into JSON then pass it to the script as an argument and deserialize it inside the script. Is there a more elegant way of achieving it than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I suggest you use the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module to parse the input of your script, so that it can parse a list of arguments as such, using the `nargs="*"` option:

```python
def main():
    """Main function of the program."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument(
        "-g", "--genes_file",
        required=True,
        help="Path to a file containing the genes.")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-o", "--output_file",
        required=True,
        help="Path to the output file.")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-f", "--frequencies",
        nargs="*",
        help="Space-separated list of frequencies.")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-t", "--threads",
        type=int,
        default=1,
        help="Number of threads to use.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # then use args.gene_file as a file name and args.frequencies as a list, etc.
```

And you would call this as follows:

```python
shell:
    """
    python scripts/create_hdf5.py \\
        -g {input.genes_file} -f {params.frequencies} \\
        -o {output} -t {threads} 2> {log.err} 1> {log.out}
    """
```

Comment: Right, it is a good practice to use the argparse overall. Thanks for the answer, I am modifying all of my scripts in this way. Meanwhile, I noticed there is also an R implementation for argparse: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/argparse/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can access the log filenames within the python script with the snakemake.log varaibale, which is a list containing both filenames:

```
snakemake.log = [ LOG_FILES+'/create_hdf5/sample_1.out', LOG_FILES+'/create_hdf5/sample_1.err' ]
```

you can thus use this within your script to create log files for logging, e.g.

```
import logging
mylogger = logging.getLogger('My logger')
# create file handler
fh = logging.FileHandler(snakemake.log[0])
mylogger.addHandler(fh)
mylogger.error("Some error")
```